# WPF Binding to Friend Property

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding

I am working on two projects:

1. A Business Logic Layer that is a class library that contains all of my objects and the business rules for my application (I am going to refer to this as my BLL)
2. A WPF application that uses the BLL

The Person class (the only class right now) within the BLL has a scope modifier set to Friend (as apposed to Public) and I have allowed the WPF application access to the class using the *Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo Attribute*.

The WPF application references the BLL and has the following components

1. A PersonViewModel class within it that wraps the BLL's Person class
2. A MainWindow.xaml (and it's corresponding MainWindow.xaml.vb file)

Since the Person class is a Friend I am forced to make the property in the PersonViewModel that exposes the Person class to the MainWindow.xaml Friend as well.

The problem is that the person's name property never shows up when I run the application.

Here is my Person class from the BLL (Please note that "WPFFriendTest" is the assembly name of the WPF application):

```
<Assembly: Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("WPFFriendTest")> 
Friend Class Person
'Public Class Person'
    Private _name As String
    Public Property Name As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        _name = "Frinavale Soldevi"

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal name As String)
        _name = name

    End Sub
End Class
```

Here is my PersonViewModel class:

```
Imports BuisnessLogicLayer

Public Class PersonViewModel
    Private _person As Person

    'Public Property Person As Person'
    Friend Property Person As Person
        Get
            Return _person
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Person)
            _person = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Sub New()
        _person = New Person
    End Sub
End Class
```

And here is my MainWindow.xaml (there is no code behind for this window):

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wpfFriendTest="clr-namespace:WPFFriendTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <wpfFriendTest:PersonViewModel x:Key="personVM"></wpfFriendTest:PersonViewModel>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DataContext="{StaticResource personVM}">
            <Label Content="Name: "></Label>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Person.Name}" Width="200"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

How can I expose the Friend property to the XAML so that it will display the property?

Thank you for your time!

-Frinny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

I made the PersonViewModel class Friend instead of Public and changed the Person Property to Public. This allowed the XAML to display the Friend information.

Like so:

```
Imports BuisnessLogicLayer

Friend Class PersonViewModel
    Private _person As Person

    'Friend Property Person As Person'
    Public Property Person As Person
        Get
            Return _person
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Person)
            _person = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Sub New()
        _person = New Person
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks again for your time

-Frinny